# How to get specific data from an api?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to print the cheapest price of an item. The issue is when a seller lists new items the API data changes. For example here is my script and price api link: [item link](https://www.bynogame.com/tr/oyunlar/csgo/skin/desert-eagle-light-rail-field-tested) and
[api link](https://integration.bynogame.com/api/listing/list/?game=csgo&item=desert-eagle-light-rail-field-tested)

```
import requests, json

params = {
    'game': 'csgo',
    'item': 'desert-eagle-light-rail-field-tested'
}

response = requests.get('https://integration.bynogame.com/api/listing/list/', params=params)

ads = json.loads(response.text)["response"]["data"]["ads"][5]
print("Fiyat:", ads["price"], "Stok:", ads["count"], "Satıcı Adı:", ads["sellerMarketName"], sep="  ")
ads = json.loads(response.text)["response"]["data"]["ads"][4]
print("Fiyat:", ads["price"], "Stok:", ads["count"], "Satıcı Adı:", ads["sellerMarketName"], sep="  ")
ads = json.loads(response.text)["response"]["data"]["ads"][3]
print("Fiyat:", ads["price"], "Stok:", ads["count"], "Satıcı Adı:", ads["sellerMarketName"], sep="  ")
ads = json.loads(response.text)["response"]["data"]["ads"][2]
print("Fiyat:", ads["price"], "Stok:", ads["count"], "Satıcı Adı:", ads["sellerMarketName"], sep="  ")
ads = json.loads(response.text)["response"]["data"]["ads"][1]
print("Fiyat:", ads["price"], "Stok:", ads["count"], "Satıcı Adı:", ads["sellerMarketName"], sep="  ")
ads = json.loads(response.text)["response"]["data"]["ads"][0]
print("Fiyat:", ads["price"], "Stok:", ads["count"], "Satıcı Adı:", ads["sellerMarketName"], sep="  ")
```

I can not figure out how to print the lowest price. Mine prints all listings if response > data > ads number matches. If not the output looks like this: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rExpx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ads = json.loads(response.text)["response"]["data"]['ads'] # grab all ads
lowest_price = ads[0]['price'] # use the first ad as the max price
for item in ads[1:]: # go through all ad items (besides first item)
    if item['price'] < lowest_price: # find the lowest price by comparing
        lowest_price = item['price'] # update lowest price if it beats previous low
print(lowest_price) # print out the final lowest price
```

Comment: And lastly i tried to loop it but cant make it. How can i loop it to print lowest price?

Comment: It already prints the lowest price out of all of the ads (the for is looping through all of the ads for that item)